# Why can't I use include?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities

That's my code:

```
ProjetoTipoCargaModelo projAux =
    dbContext.ProjetoTipoCargaDbSet.Find(idProjetoTipoCarga);
ICollection<ProjetoTipoCargaRegraModelo> regras =
    projAux.ListaRegra.Where(x => x.Ativo).ToList();
IQueryable<ProjetoTipoCargaRegraModelo> pr =
    dbContext.ProjetoTipoCargaDbSet.Select(
        x => regras.FirstOrDefault(y => y.IdProjetoTipoCarga == x.IdProjetoTipoCarga));

var projetoCompleto = pr.
    Include(x => x.ListaRegraLiberacaoInicioViagem).
    Include(x => x.ListaRegraTecnologiaAceita).
    Include(x => x.RegraAreaSombra).
    Include(x => x.RegraAtuadorNecessario)
```

It's showing an error at first include, but I'm trying to do it on Iquerable object!

What's wrong where?

**My problem is make this include in a filtered set of results.**

**[Edit]**
Error:

**Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type**

It's not a runtime error, it's a compilation error.

**[Edit 2]**
My usings:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
```

**[Edit 3]**
Answer:

```
ICollection<ProjetoTipoCargaRegraModelo> regras = projAux.ListaRegra.Where(x => x.Ativo).ToList();
IQueryable<ProjetoTipoCargaModelo> pr = dbContext.ProjetoTipoCargaDbSet.Where(x => x.IdProjetoTipoCarga == regras.FirstOrDefault(y => y.IdProjetoTipoCarga == x.IdProjetoTipoCarga).IdProjetoTipoCarga);

var projetoCompleto = pr.
    Include(x => x.ListaRegraLiberacaoInicioViagem).
    Include(x => x.ListaRegraTecnologiaAceita).
    Include(x => x.RegraAreaSombra).
```

Comment: If you managed to figure out the answer yourself, feel free to post it as an answer to your own question (rather than putting it in an edit in your question). It doesn't look like your answer is really an answer, though. You've solved a problem, certainly, but the problem you solved doesn't look like it could've led to the error you were getting.

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to the `Include`s.

You can't use `regas` in a LINQ-to-entities query because it's an `ICollection`. EF can't translate that into SQL.

Your "answer" can't possibly work with EF. The object `regas` is an in-memory list of `Regra` entities (I guess). If you use that directly in...

```
var pr = dbContext.ProjetoTipoCargaDbSet
        .Where(x => x.IdProjetoTipoCarga == regras.FirstOrDefault(y => y.IdProjetoTipoCarga == x.IdProjetoTipoCarga).IdProjetoTipoCarga);
```

...you should get an exception like

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Regra'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported...

But, boy, what a tortuous way to get where you want to be! First you get a `ProjetoTipoCargaModelo` object by an `idProjetoTipoCarga`. Then you fetch its active `Regra`s. Then you basically use the `IdProjetoTipoCarga` values of the `Regra`s to see if one of them is equal to the original `idProjetoTipoCarga` and if so, you use its value to get a `ProjetoTipoCargaModelo` object.

If you remove all the redundancies, what's left is:

```
var pr = dbContext.ProjetoTipoCargaDbSet
                  .Where(x => x.IdProjetoTipoCarga == idProjetoTipoCarga
                           && x.ListaRegra.Any(r => r.Ativo));
```

I you us this LINQ statement, you append your includes to `pr`.

Answer (score 0):

The .Include() method only works on `ObjectQuery<TEntity>`

Try:

```
context.EntitySet.Include(...).Select(...)
```

instead of:

```
context.EntitySet.Select(...).Include(...)
```

or use an extenion method like this:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> Include<TEntity>(
        this IQueryable<TEntity> query, string path)
    {
        var efQuery = query as ObjectQuery<TEntity>;
        if (efQuery == null)
            return query;

        return efQuery.Include(path);
    }
}
```

or better yet, use **the already available extension method** that supports lambda expressions instead of strings as paths.

Also, do not use so many includes unless most are 1:1 or *:1 relationships, 1:* (or *:*) relationships greatly increase the IO from the database, resulting in bad performance.

Consider using multiple queries with .Future() to enable a single access to the database instead.

Comment: What's the vote down for - this answer **DOES** work. I have used all these options multiple times.

Comment: @hvd I know, my answer does say that the extension method already exists, I was simply demonstrating how.

Comment: @hvd read the answer to the end, it explains why it does work, all the alternatives for making it work and why none of them should be used and what to do instead.

Comment: @hvg note the first part of my answer - changing the order of the operations can enable usage of .Include() without any extension methods.

Comment: I agree that my previous comments missed the point. In the question, the OP is attempting to call `Include` on an `IQueryable<ProjetoTipoCargaRegraModelo>`, though, and I'm not getting from your answer why that wouldn't compile, and why your change would solve it.

Comment: @hvd open up a compiler and see for yourself.

Comment: What, to verify that an extension method defined for `IQueryable<T>` can not only be called with a `IQueryable<ProjetoTipoCargaModelo>`, but also with a `IQueryable<ProjetoTipoCargaRegraModelo>`? I've used that `Include` extension method with many `IQueryable<T>`'s, but I don't speak the OP's language, so none of my classes have ever been named `ProjetoTipoCargaRegraModelo`. :)